# C++/CX HTTP Web Server for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I need to run an HTTP web server in a Windows Store app written in C++/CX and XAML. I'm implementing a WinRT version of Readium (an ePub reader, [here's a link to the MFC version for reference](https://github.com/readium/SDKLauncher-Windows)).  The MFC version uses [Microsoft's Sample HTTP Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this is incompatible with WinRT sadly.

Googling reveals no embeddable HTTP servers for C++/CX so I'll ask directly: does anyone know of an HTTP server written in C++/CX?

If there is no server written in C++/CX is there one written in another WinRT language (C# for instance) that can interop with C++/CX?

Comment: You cannot have a http server running inside a Windows Store app

Comment: @RamanSharma Could you provide a link to some documentation that states this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was never able to find an HTTP server that would run inside a WinRT app though I believe it is technically possible. However, it turns out I didn't need a full HTTP server as the Windows `WebView` has a method called [NavigateToLocalStreamUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn299344) that allows me to manually handle requests for files in the `WebView` (e.g., images, stylesheets) and return them to the `WebView` similar to how an HTTP server would.

MSDN provides a [simple example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/20/a-primer-on-webview-navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx) that resolves an image an HTML page in a `WebView`.